# Visual Studio Cordova deploy to remote iOS 10 Device Failing

Tags: iphone, xcode, visual-studio, cordova, ios10

I had successfully set up remote deployment from Visual Studio on my Windows machine to iOS 9.x devices with Xcode 7.x on my mac by following this guide.

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/

With iOS 10 you need to upgrade to Xcode 8 and do some tweaking to get your developer team identifier in the build config to get it to sign properly.  Thanks to this guide I was able to get a successful compile.

https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html

However I'm still getting this error that I can't find a fix for within remotebuild.

```
Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app. See Output window for JavaScript console output.
Http 404: Error mounting developer disk image
Http 500: No devices found to debug. Please ensure that a device is connected and awake and retry.
```

I have tried changing the remotebuild timeout settings and of course restarting/re-plugging in the device.

I am able to open the .xcodeproj in Xcode and deploy it from the Mac directly.  Or else take the .ipa file and drop it into iTunes to install.

Has anybody found a solution for remotebuild to deploy to iOS 10 devices when they get this error?

Comment: I have the exact same error. The iOS 10 update definitely messed something up.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Remotebuild, same "Error mounting developer disk image" followed by "No devices found to debug..." Upgraded to Xcode 8, iOS 10.0.2. `developmentTeam` is set. I can build and run the project with`cordova run ios --device` from the remotebuild temp directory on Mac. If you happen to resolve this, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This fixed it for me:)

Run from Terminal:
brew upgrade libimobiledevice --HEAD

Read more:
https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/5

Comment: Yep, this was the solution for me too.

Comment: Confirmed solution.  Be sure you use two hyphens unlike I did the first time I tried!