# Cordova "Error mounting to image" and "No devices found to debug" on Remote Build to Mac using Xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, macos, cordova

I am trying to debug my cordova project on an iPhone using a remote build on my mac. The build is successful but when trying to deploy I get the following two error messages:

> Failed to launch iOS remote for build
>   C:\Flex\Trunk\Flex.Net\Flex.Net.MobileHybrid\bld\ios\Release\buildInfo.json`
>   to http://[ipadress]:port/cordova :  Http 404: Error mounting
>   developer disk image

Regarding this error, this is what I've already tried and has not helped:

- Restarting all devices
- Making sure that I actually have a disk image for each iOS by checking in folder Finder > Xcode > Show Package Contents > Developer > Platforms > DeviceSupport.
- Downloading latest XCode, Cordova and iOS (10.0.2) on my phone.
- Using a phone with a lower version iOS (9.3).

> Failed to Debug iOS remote for build
>   C:\Flex\Trunk\Flex.Net\Flex.Net.MobileHybrid\bld\ios\Release\buildInfo.json
>   to http://[ipadress]:port/cordova :
>       Http 500: No devices found to debug. Please ensure that a device is connected and awake and retry.

And in regards to this error, what I've tried is the following:

- Making sure all different kinds of apple developer certificates are as they should be. I have also tried to debug the device on XCode on my Mac, which works fine.
- I have tried restarting all devices involved and update everything (xcode, visual studio, iOS, cordova, plugins etc), and tried registering a different iPhone as well.

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be causing this? I feel like I have tried almost everything.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after the iOS 10 update. If you find a solution, please post it as an answer here. I assume you already took care of the `developmentTeam` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501020/code-sign-error-on-xcode-8-and-ios-10-cordova-project

Comment: Yes, I took care of that and it didn't help. I have not found any solutions yet but if you just want a workaround to test your project on an iOS-device, what works for me is opening the .xcodeproj-file generated from cordova manually in XCode, and then build the project

Comment: Thank you @Ola Parmos. My workaround was `cordova run ios --device` from the remotebuild temp directory on Mac. I would still want to solve the original Visual Studio issue. Device testing is slow as it is, manual steps just add to it. I do a lot of filesystem operations, there is no other way to test it for me.

Comment: I can confirm that I can deploy to the device now by updating the library with Brew.  However, I haven't successfully been able to debug yet.

brew upgrade libimobiledevice --HEAD

It's described in the thread below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624131/visual-studio-cordova-deploy-to-remote-ios-10-device-failing?rq=1

Comment: @CoreyRoth Please read my reply. I was able to debug by following the last step: brew upgrade ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Answer (score 1):

I tried Zelina's solution, I got this message `Error: libimobiledevice HEAD-45fda81 already installed` and somehow it continued to fail (Http 404 and 500).

So I followed these steps in my MAC terminal:

- brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
- brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force libimobiledevice
- brew update && brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD && brew install ideviceinstaller ios-webkit-debug-proxy
- brew upgrade ios-webkit-debug-proxy

If you don't get any installation errors, try to debug with VS2015 again and this time it should work.

I hope it helps someone out there as I spent way too long to find this solution and I know the frustration.

Comment: This helped me get my app deployed to a new device. It's still not debugging properly and freezes VS upon deploy, but it's a good start. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, I upgraded the library that enables deploying on devices on my mac `brew upgrade libimobiledevice --HEAD` and now i can succesfully deploy with Visual Studio.